# Adding a calculation to a tuple

Tags: haskell

I have two functions

```
somefunc:: (Floating a, Ord a) => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> a

pairs :: (Floating a, Ord a) =>[(a,a)] -> (a,a) -> [((a, a), a)]
pairs xs p = zip xs (map (somefunc p) xs)
```

I am trying to make a calculation with some func and append this to each tuple.
My code compiles, however when I try to execute my code like this

```
pairs [1,1] (1,1)
```

I get the following error

```
<interactive>:49:1: error:
• Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a, a)
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
• When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall a. (Num (a, a), Ord a, Floating a) => [((a, a), a)]
```

Could someone explain this error to me?

Comment: `pairs` takes a list of **pairs** and a pair. You are sending it a list of **numbers** and a pair.

Answer (score 3):

You are putting the wrong types into your function

```
pairs [1,1] (1,1)
```

Should be `pairs [(1,1)] (1,1)`

The error message you get is because the compiler tries to convert a `1` (list element) into a pair `??` but fails to do so.